# Use tcl interp alias to rename tcl built in command

Tags: hide, tcl, alias, interpreter, slave

How can I rename an existing tcl command in a slave interpreter?

In other words

```
interp create test
test alias __proc proc

test eval {
  __proc hello {} {
    puts "hiya"
  }
  hello
}
```

This unfortunately does not work. However, if I hide and expose under a different name that works. But, I would like to use both commands `proc` and `__proc` - so I would prefer to use aliases, or any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alias` command on a Tcl interpreter allows you to create a command in an interpreter that causes code to run in a *different* interpreter. So that's not what you want.

I think the following does what you want:

```
interp create test

test eval {
  rename proc __proc

  __proc hello {} {
        puts "hiya"
  }

  hello
}
```

You can then combine the creation of the interpreter with the renaming of the proc command as follows:

```
proc myinterp {interpName newProcName} {
   interp create $interpName
   $interpName eval "rename proc $newProcName"
}

myinterp test func

test eval { func greet {} { puts "hello" } }
test eval ( greet }
```

Comment: Oh I see. Is it possible to have proc and __proc work in the same interpreter? So, func and proc could work in test?

Comment: Nevermind got it! interp alias interpname __proc interpname proc

Answer (score 0):

You can do either

```
interp alias test __proc test proc
```

in the main interp or

```
interp alias {} __proc {} proc
```

in the slave, so both of the following scrips work:

```
interp create test
interp alias test __proc test proc

test eval {
  __proc hello {} {
    puts "hiya"
  }
  hello
}
```

or

```
interp create test

test eval {
interp alias {} __proc {} proc
  __proc hello {} {
    puts "hiya"
  }
  hello
}
```

`test alias __proc proc` is the same as `interp alias test __proc {} proc`, that means that `__proc` in the slave will call `proc` in the master.